# Formatting numbers in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

For a `NumberTextBox` I need to display its value in a percentage format, for example if value is `0.5` I need to display `50%`.

Currently I am using the `pattern: "#%"` but it shows the wrong value.

Could you please suggest me how to fix it?

Optional:

Is it possible also to show also the value without percentage if possible example only `50`.

I also tried `pattern:"#,##0.0%"` but with no success.

https://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/ejnar255/

```
<label for="programmatic">Opacity:</label>
<input id="programmatic" type="text" />


require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(NumberTextBox) {
    new NumberTextBox({
        name: "programmatic",
        constraints: {
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            pattern: "#%"
        },
        value: 0.5
    }, "programmatic").startup();
});
```

Related documentation:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/numbersDates.html

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/NumberTextBox.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the following pattern:

`pattern:"#.##%"`

https://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/ejnar255/

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(NumberTextBox) {
    new NumberTextBox({
        name: "programmatic",
        constraints: {
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            pattern:"#.##%"
        },
        value: 0.25
    }, "programmatic").startup();
});


<label for="programmatic">Opacity:</label>
<input id="programmatic" type="text" />
```